# Error When running application after upgrading EntityFramework from 4 to 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

> Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error:

```
GemAtlas.Data.Entity.GemAtlasEntities edmx = new GemAtlas.Data.Entity.GemAtlasEntities();
```

Comment: looks like you have not installed the framework correctly. Please re-install. If the problem persists, let us know.

Comment: reinstall EF6 package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/6.1.3

Comment: After deployment its working fine